# Disable everything in background while a popup is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a HTML, JQuery and CSS-based webpage on which I want to open popup using simple div tag. I want to disable everything in the background while a popup is open. That means while the popup div is visible to the user, he or she should not be able to click anything else on the webpage (anything behind or in the background of popup).

Following is how I am trying to do it. I open a popup by clicking on an HTML button (#but1) and close it using the button (#but2) by applying the following jquery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#but1").click(function(){
            $("#popdiv").fadeTo(200,1);           
        });
    $("#but2").click(function(){
            $("#popdiv").fadeOut(200);              
        });
});
```

The CSS for the popup div is -

```
#popdiv
{
    height:300px;
    width:420px;
    background-color:#97ceaa;
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
    left:250px;
    display:none;
}
```

I want to disable the background after my popup div appears on the webpage. After my popup appears the mouse effects should be disabled, and the user should not be able to click/hover anything else on the webpage (in the background of popup). User will need to close the popup to access the webpage. How can I achieve this? Is it possible to do this using only CSS?

Comment: can you post the relative html code also or working snippet

Comment: answer in the article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103723/disable-background-using-css-when-popup-appear should be helpful to you.... otherwise you can provide html details to us.

Comment: Newcomers be aware! Setting the popup over the screen or using some z-index hack can easily be bypassed by the inspect tab. So don't use this method if you want to strictly disable the user to interact with the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put it inside another container that fills the page (and show that):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#but1").click(function() {
    $(".fullscreen-container").fadeTo(200, 1);
  });
  $("#but2").click(function() {
    $(".fullscreen-container").fadeOut(200);
  });
});
```

```css
.fullscreen-container {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.5);
  z-index: 9999;
}

#popdiv {
  height: 300px;
  width: 420px;
  background-color: #97ceaa;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

body {
  padding-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but1">Open dialog</button>
<div class="fullscreen-container">
  <div id="popdiv">
    <h1>
      Dialog content!
    </h1>
    <button id="but2">Close dialog</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask why you use such a high number for your z-index?

Comment: @Gezzasa To make it most likely that this element will be on top.

Comment: This is what i was looking for.... thank you....

Comment: This will work until the user (shift+)tabs through your elements and can now press buttons you intended to disable.

Comment: This is not a complete solution!
Assuming there are other controls under the shield that may get focus - like an <input type="text" />, that control may get focus using the keyboard (with TAB or SHIFT+TAB) and can be modified under the shield with the keyboard!
I'm still looking for a complete solution, with no luck yet!

Answer (score 5):

You might want this:

A backdrop surrounding your popup which covers the entire screen on top of other elements.
**A structure like this:**

```
+--------------------+
| BackDrop           |
|                    |
|  +--------------+  |
|  | Pop Up       |  |
|  |              |  | 
|  +--------------+  |
|                    |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#but1").click(function() {
    $(".backdrop").fadeTo(200, 1);
  });
  $("#but2").click(function() {
    $(".backdrop").fadeOut(200);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#popdiv {
  height: 40%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #97ceaa;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="but1">Open</button>
<div class="backdrop">
  <div id="popdiv">
    <button id="but2">Close</button
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution!
Assuming there are other controls under the shield that may get focus - like an <input type="text" />, that control may get focus using the keyboard (with TAB or SHIFT+TAB) and can be modified under the shield with the keyboard!
I'm still looking for acomplete solution, with no luck yet!

Answer (score 3):

Create a background `div` with the property [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), for example:

```
#disableDiv {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

Before showing your popup, show the background div, it will make impossible to click/hover on the elements "behind" it.