# How to make all background unclickable when my popup is displayed on blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, blogs

I want to disable my background until user click on X button.
I am using the below css code to block the entire page when the popup appeared. But it's working(The visible page only covered not all). I have a problem, if my page having a scroll bar means the remaining bottom of the page not covered by the blocker.

```css
#pop {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 7px;
  z-index: 999;
}

#close {
  right: 5;
  top: 5;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="pop">
  <button id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('pop').style.display='none'">X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable everything in background while a popup is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327854/disable-everything-in-background-while-a-popup-is-opened)

Comment: I am not using jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

---

Try this it should help

```css
.display {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
}

.display2 {
  background-color: White;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 1001;
  top: 60px;
  left: 240px;
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<div style="display">
  <div id="divOperationMessage" style="display2">
    ---------content inside---------

  </div>
  <div>
    <a id="myPopup" href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Click</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // When the user clicks on div, open the popup
  function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How to add close button on it?

Comment: I just want that the code must be same as mine  with added z-index and when I click on x then both z-index and popup get closed!