# Turning on and off a click event

Tags: jquery, onclick, event-handling, jquery-events

So I'm trying to make a photo gallery where:
1.If you click on one of the photos there's a pop up
2.But you cannot click on any photos again until you close the pop up.

I've already messed around with click events and turning them on and off. Right now I have it working so that when I click a photo the pop up comes and I can't click any of the photos. However I'm having trouble turning the click function back after I click close.

```
$("#th1").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown").animate({
        top: "+=400"
    }, 500);
    //fix the pop up so it won't scroll
    $("#dropdown").addClass("fixed");
    //prevent clicking again
    $("#th1,#th2,#th3,#th4,#th5,#th6").off('click');
});

//close the pop up
$('#closedPopUp').click(function(event) {
    //prevent the default functionality
    event.preventDefault();
    //move the pop up back off the screen
    $("#dropdown").css("top", "-250px");
    //turn clicking on again (this part doesn't work)
    $("#th1,#th2,#th3,#th4,#th5,#th6").on('click');
});
```

Comment: No need to do `.off`. Make sure your pop-up comes up with a full overlay on the site and can be closed only by clicking on the pop-up close button. That's it

Comment: check this example for the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328058/4248328

Comment: Sounds like you want [`pointer-events:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) which you can add to css then add/remove a class on your TH's.

Comment: .on()/.off() mean "do this when user clicks, stop doing that when user clicks" - and you must provide the "this/that" - it's not just whether click events fire or not (that's pointer-events)

Comment: To achieve your goal of only one popup, many modal/dialog plugins create a "backdrop" that covers all other controls, so you then can't click on another one until you close the popup/dialog/modal and its corresponding backdrop.  This also provides a nice UX where the backdrop would be semi-transparent and thus "grey-out" everything not on the popup, so the popup is more prominent.  **Edit** "backdrop" is synonymous with "overlay" as already commented above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
$("#th1,#th2,#th3,#th4,#th5,#th6").on('click');
```

this does literally nothing, because there is no argument what to do on click.

You can assign your function to a variable to make it work:

```
var clickFunction = function() {
    // ...
    //prevent clicking again
    $("#th1,#th2,#th3,#th4,#th5,#th6").off('click');
}

$("#th1").click(clickFunction);

//close the pop up
$('#closedPopUp').click(function(event) {
    // ...
    $("#th1,#th2,#th3,#th4,#th5,#th6").on('click', clickFunction);
});
```